# Smart Client, as opposed to Thin/Thick Client- Examples

Tags: smartclient, thin-client, thick-client

What is a Smart client, as opposed to a Thin or Thick client, and what would be a good example(s) to exemplify this concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this Wikipedia article does a pretty good job at explaining the concept http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_client and it gives the original use and concepts in the article.

Comment: It is a concise and fairly demonstrative article. Thanks.